# Trying to resolve ClassNotFound error when running program using OrmLite

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, ormlite

I am trying to use OrmLite to connect to a SQLite database (not android). I have read the docs and I believe that my code is correct but I am getting a runtime error when trying to run. I am using Maven to import the dependencies.

Here is my code:

```
public class AddressBook {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        ConnectionSource connectionSource =
            new JdbcConnectionSource("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");
        Dao<Person, Integer> personDao =
            DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Person.class);
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is the dependency section of my maven POM file:

```
  <dependencies>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.36.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.j256.ormlite/ormlite-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.48</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.j256.ormlite/ormlite-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I am trying to run the program in Eclipse. I checked the Run Configuration and it shows Maven Dependencies in the classpath on the Dependencies tab. Here is the error I am getting when running in Eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/j256/ormlite/field/converter/BooleanNumberFieldConverter
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.db.SqlServerDatabaseType.<clinit>(SqlServerDatabaseType.java:31)
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.db.DatabaseTypeUtils.<clinit>(DatabaseTypeUtils.java:31)
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.BaseJdbcConnectionSource.initialize(BaseJdbcConnectionSource.java:102)
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.<init>(JdbcConnectionSource.java:104)
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.<init>(JdbcConnectionSource.java:47)
    at dev.website.addressbook.AddressBook.main(AddressBook.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.j256.ormlite.field.converter.BooleanNumberFieldConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 6 more
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's not a compiler error, and you didn't show how you're trying to launch the application.

Comment: You're right @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I updated my question, sorry I am new to Java. I am just trying to run it in Eclipse. I did check the run config and it shows maven dependencies. I'm not sure if I might be missing a step there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` generally occurs when you have a `Class A` trying to access a `Class B` and the `Class B` is not available in the `classpath`. Simply say, in `Class A` you have :

```
import com.company.ClassB;

class A {

}
```

and then in the `jar` of the `Class B`, `Class B` is no longer available there.

In your case, it is an incompatibility of the version between `ormlite-core` and `ormlite-jdbc`. The Class `SqlServerDatabaseType` in `ormlite-jdbc` is looking for the class `BooleanNumberFieldConverter` in `ormlite-core` which is no longer available in the version `4.48` of `ormlite-core`.

To resolve your issue, you have to change the version of `ormlite-core` to `5.6`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ormlite-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.6</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ormlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>5.6</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It really helped me out! I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.

When I imported ormlite-core and ormlite-jdbc, I imported different versions of them. I changed it in my maven POM to where it is the same version and that corrected the issue!

This is what I changed my maven POM dependencies to:

```
<dependencies>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.36.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.j256.ormlite/ormlite-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.j256.ormlite/ormlite-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```